# CombineLatest with result of pieces

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I want a stream that emit when some observables change, but result of one observable is needed to others.

This is the base code:

```
combineLatest ([
  obs1$,
  obs2$.pipe (... /* In this point I would the result of obs1$ */)
])
```

I use the combineLatest as I said before, because I want a stream that emit when every observables change, but the first one is needed for successors.
How can I achive this?

Comment: Your use case is not clear.  Can you explain more?  You could do what @Octavian suggests below, or you could just put your pipe after the combineLatest `combineLatest([obs1$, obs2$]).pipe(map(([val1, val2]) => {...})`

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`withLatestFrom`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/withLatestFrom) to achieve what you want:

```js
combineLatest ([
  obs1$,
  obs2$.pipe(
    withLatestFrom(obs1$),
    switchMap(([obs2Event, obs1Event]) => myService.getData(obs1Event, obs2Event)
  )
]);
```